# execute function after a $router.go in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Can someone tell how can I execute a function after a
this.$router.go(-1)
if it's possible. I've tried with a nextTick but I think it's not correct.

Comment: what does that function do ? what scope it requires ?

Comment: the idea is that previously I have to check if the user is logged, not-logged or member.
if the user is not a partner or not logged I have to send back and show a panel to just log-in or turn him/her into a partner

Comment: why not do it before `router.go()`? anyway answering the question shortly.

Answer (score 1):

If the function you want to execute and the `router.go` are in the same component, once the router.go is fired, If there is a page change, it means the component gets unmounted, which in turn means the function cannot get executed. What I think you can do is to look for a hook that would help you.

You can call your function within the `beforeRouteLeave` router hook. Check implementation in the official [vue router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards). This will fire before the router.go is called

You could also use one of the component lifecycle hooks - `beforeDestroy`.
if your component is getting unmounted. So, you can fire your function inside the beforeDestroy method.

Comment: the problem is that what I need to execute in the function in not in the first component, it is in the other view where I send the user.

Comment: If the function you want to execute is in the other component, you can still use one of the hooks. either the router hook `beforeRouteEnter` or the vue component life cycle hooks `created` or `mounted`